# How can i make a property value inside an ngfor independent, between two child components?

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

When clicking on a car brand, i need it to be displayed on the bottom, where it has the name of the person, and its favorite car, cliked above, but when i click on one, the car brand is repeated between all items of the ngfor.

stackblitz example of it:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rjdhkh?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.html

[image: image example]

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rjdhkh?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary to hold the values for each person using their name as the key. See the edited stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pachaq?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Just use input when rendering every component in your ngfor.
https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).